# How to successfully match google.com within my regex? Negative lookbehind or the OR statement doesn't seem to work

Tags: regex

Given this regex

```
((https?:\/\/(www\.))?(https?:\/\/)?(www\.))[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._+~#=]{1,256}\.[a-zA-Z0-9()]{1,6}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9()@:%_+.~#?&//=]*)
```

Everything matches correctly except `google.com` and negative lookbehind or the `|` statement doesn't seem to work correctly.

```
www.google.com foo https://www.google.com bar google.com
```

https://regexr.com/6q91r

Comment: Where's the negative lookbehind and where the `|`? And I don't see how you only match Google.

Comment: @xehpuk That is my issue, I want to also match `google.com` if `((https?:\/\/(www\.))?(https?:\/\/)?(www\.))` this doesn't exist. I tried to put `|` after this matcher, but it's not working like i want it to. 

`www.` or `https://www.` should be conditional.

Comment: Perhaps something like this https://regex101.com/r/1rMl8Z/1 but note that your pattern is not related to matching goole.com